# iOS NSDictionary: long value for one key

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I've got the a NSDictionary (lets call it NSDictionary x) that has a long object for one of its keys:

> @"pubDate" : (long)1399064580000

But when using:

> NSInteger a = [[x objectForKey:@"pubDate"] longValue];

Instead of getting the correct value ((long)1399064580000) I get -1094758496 (so a is = to -1094758496 instead of 1399064580000).

I also tried the following with the same result:

> NSInteger a = [[x objectForKey:@"pubDate"] intValue];
>   
>   NSInteger a = [[x objectForKey:@"pubDate"] integerValue];
>   
>   NSInteger a = [x valueForKey:@"pubDate"]; => this one gives another number that it's neither the correct value.

Anybody knows whats going on? Why I ain't getting the correct long value into "a"?

Thanks in advance for any help, really appreciate it!

Comment: try to use [NSNumber numberWithLong:pubDate]

Comment: How did you create the value and assign it to the dictionary?

Comment: you may want to parse it as `long long`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSInteger` and `long` are only 32 bit on 32 bit systems, so `1399064580000` won't fit into a `long` variable. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

try using `long long` as datatype and `longLongValue` to get it out of the dictionary.